# Is it possible to create mail by directly including the html from an html file?

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm setting up a Excel file with any amount of email addresses and for each a column with the subject.

I want to send personalized emails to the addresses based on the subject.

So if email address x has subject y, I want to get the html script for this email out of a html file which I have created for all emails with this subject.

I thought I could realize it by getting the mailitem.htmlbody directly out of the different html files which I will create for each subject. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody

I tried to get the body text out of a html file.

```
Sub Send_email_fromexcel()
Dim edress As String
Dim subj As String
Dim message As String
Dim filename, fname2 As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim myAttachments As Object
Dim path As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim attachment As String
Dim x As Integer

x = 2

Do While Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) does not equal ""

    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
    Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments
    path = "C:\Users\Barb\Documents\statements\"
    edress = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)

    subj = Sheet1.Cells(x, 2)
    filename = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3)
    fname2 = "excellogo.jpg"
    attachment = path + filename

    outlookmailitem.To = edress
    outlookmailitem.cc = ""
    outlookmailitem.bcc = ""
    outlookmailitem.Subject = subj
    outlookmailitem.Attachments.Add path & fname2, 0
    outlookmailitem.HTMLBody = "Thank you for your contract br" _
      & "  br We will work to acheive the results you require.br" _
      & "br For any further questions please feel free to contact us any time br " _
      & "br or visit our website at www.easyexcelanswers.com br" _
      & "p:(780) 499-6658 br" _
      & "Canada br" _
      & "  br img src='excellogo.jpg'" & "width='146' height='138'"

    //->> here I want to get the html out of a seperate file instead of writing the text into the code

    'outlookmailitem.body = "Please find your statement attached" & vbCrLf & "Best Regards"

    myAttachments.Add (attachment)
    outlookmailitem.display
    'outlookmailitem.send

    lastrow = lastrow + 1
    edress = ""
    x = x + 1
Loop

Set outlookapp = Nothing
Set outlookmailitem = Nothing

End Sub
```

I expect to have a personalized email for each contact, based on his gender/name and the mail subject.

Answer (score 0):

Read the html file and include that in the code.
I assume it's `filename` you want.

```
Dim html As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile

Open filenameFor Input As #iFile
html = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
Close #iFile
```

Then append the html to your body.

```
outlookmailitem.HTMLBody = "Thank you for your contract br" _
    & "  br We will work to acheive the results you require.br" _
    & "br For any further questions please feel free to contact us any time br " _
    & "br or visit our website at www.easyexcelanswers.com br" _
            & "p:(780) 499-6658 br" _
            & "Canada br" _
            & "  br img src='excellogo.jpg'" & "width='146' height='138'"
            & html
```